# Correct code for multiple conditions for else if

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, sqlite, nested-loops

Hi im having difficulties in this code, i think my if else conditions are wrong.

When you run the program, if the user inputs nothing, it sends 'list-group-item-danger' which is the first if statement, then if the user inputs both NAME and PLACE, it sends 'list-group-item-success'. Both are correct.

> if the user input at least one input (NAME or PLACE) it sends
>   'list-group-item-success' also which is wrong, because it doesn't
>   satisfy the condition on the 2nd if statement (PLACE and(&&) NAME), it
>   should be on the last statement which it sends
>   'list-group-item-warning'

```js
var obj = {};
   db.all("SELECT * FROM f41 WHERE id = ?",[id], function(err,rows){   
if((rows[0].NAME == null || rows[0].NAME == '') && (rows[0].PLACE == null || rows[0].PLACE == ''))
 {
    obj.f41='list-group-item-danger';
 }
else if((rows[0].NAME != null || rows[0].NAME != '') && (rows[0].PLACE != null || rows[0].PLACE != ''))
 {
   obj.f41='list-group-item-success';
 }
 else
 {
   obj.f41='list-group-item-warning';
 }
  res.send(obj);
   });
```

Comment: Your snippet is showing error.Can you add a working snippet

Comment: already edited the code, i think it should work now

Answer (score 2):

In my understanding, issue is here:

```
(rows[0].NAME != null || rows[0].NAME != '')
```

If `row[0].NAME` is `null`, its not equal to `""` and vice-versa. Hence it will return true.

You can try

```
!(rows[0].NAME == null || rows[0].NAME === '')
```

You can also try to create a utils function `isEmpty`

```js
var obj = {};
db.all("SELECT * FROM f41 WHERE id = ?", [id], function(err, rows) {
  if (isEmpty(rows[0].NAME) && isEmpty(rows[0].PLACE)) {
    obj.f41 = 'list-group-item-danger';
  } 
  else if (!isEmpty(rows[0].NAME) && !isEmpty(rows[0].PLACE)) {
    obj.f41 = 'list-group-item-success';
  } else {
    obj.f41 = 'list-group-item-warning';
  }
  res.send(obj);
});

function isEmpty(v){
  return v === null || v.toString().trim().length === 0
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can improve your conditions like this

```
if(rows[0].NAME && rows[0].PLACE) {
    obj.f41='list-group-item-success';
} else if(!rows[0].NAME && !rows[0].PLACE) {
    obj.f41='list-group-item-danger';
} else {
    obj.f41='list-group-item-warning';
}
```

Comment: Note, in JS `false` and `0` are also falsey

Comment: @Rajesh I know it, but looking at question, i think it's a string.... So no consideration of 0 required here